# Как очистить файл от HTML-тегов и вывести только текст?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x

Надо очистить файл от HTML-тегов и вывести на экран «чистый» текст.

Могу вывести все HTML коды из текста, но не знаю как их удалить из текста и вывести чистый текст.

```
import re
import urllib.request
url = "http://dfedorov.spb.ru/python/files/p.html"
with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as webpage, open('mail.txt', 'r') as fw:
    for line in webpage:
        line = line.strip()
        line = line.decode('utf-8')
        urls = ''.join(re.findall(r'<[^>]+>', line))
        print(urls)
```

Comment: Про какой текст идет речь? Контент тегов (параграфов, ...)?

Comment: Не дубликат, т.к. там вопрос скорее по регулярным выражениям (прямо в заголовке это написано), а здесь конкретно упор на Python, а для этого языка есть средства без использования регулярок.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
data = urllib.request.urlopen(url).read().decode("utf-8")
res = re.sub(r"<[^>]+>", "", data, flags=re.S)
print(res)
```

вывод:

```
    
       
       Абзацы
    
    
        Абзац - отрезок письменной речи, состоящий из нескольких предложений.
        Выделение фразы в особый абзац  усиливает падающий на него смысловой акцент.
        Для выделения абзаца его,  помимо новой строки, печатают со строки красной,  то есть отделяют вертикальным отступом  от соседних абзацев и/или делают абзацный отступ.
```

PS я исходил из того, что это задачка по регулярным выражениям. Если же это реальная задача по парсингу/обработке HTML, тогда стоит воспользоваться специально разработанным для этого инструментом - `BeautifulSoup`:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text)
text = soup.get_text()
```

Answer (score 6):

Попробуйте модуль `bleach`:

```
# pip install bleach
import bleach

html = '<p><span>is not <b><span>allowed</span></b></span></p>'
print(bleach.clean(html, tags=[], strip=True))
# is not allowed
```